Persistent Disconnection Issues with Colab Pro Runtime
I am a Colab Pro subscriber experiencing persistent issues with my runtime. I'm writing to seek
assistance in resolving this problem.
Issue Description:
My Colab Pro runtime is disconnecting approximately every minute.
This issue is making it extremely difficult to complete any work or run extended processes.
The problem has been occurring consistently, regardless of the notebook I'm working on.
Details:
Subscription: Colab Pro
Frequency of disconnections: Every time I reach the train-test-split
Browser: Google Chrome
I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide in resolving this issue. If you need any additional information or logs, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide them.
Thank you for your time and support.
Best regards.
Steps I've already taken:
Checked and confirmed my internet connection is stable
Cleared browser cache and cookies
Tried using a different browser
Attempted to use both CPU and GPU runtimes
Checked for any code that might be causing high resource usage

Have you contacted Google for support? Seems like you should be able to do that as a paid user. We can't do customer service here.
